# Take text from several elements and add it to others, but dynamically with javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I've created this very simple structure just to describe what I want to do, let's say all the text in the `name` class is rendered, and I'm trying to find a way to make all the text in that class dynamically inserted into each  `#link`, but without overwriting the name but concatenating, it would look like this test 02 Hulk and Test 02 Deadpool

```
jQuery('#link').append(jQuery('.name').text());

<nav class="navigation">
    <ul id="navigation-item">
        <li class="first">
          <a class="name"> Hulk</a>
            <ul>
                <div>
                    <li>
                        <p>
                            test 00
                        </p>
                    </li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li>
                        <p>
                            test 01
                        </p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <p>
                           <a id="link">test 02</a> 
                        </p>
                    </li>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </li>
         <li class="second">
          < a class="name"> Deadpool <a/>
            <ul>
                <div>
                    <li>
                        <p>
                            test 00
                        </p>
                    </li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li>
                        <p>
                            test 01
                        </p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <p>
                           <a id="link">test 02</a> 
                        </p>
                    </li>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I created this structure as an example but it didn't work, because it takes the name Hulk and Deadpool and inserts everything together

Comment: `div` isn't a valid child of a list element.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do is correct your HTML. Firstly you cannot have mulitiple elements in the DOM with the same `id` attribute. They need to be unique. In this case you are looking to group the elements so use a common class instead.

Secondly you cannot have a `div` as a child of a `ul` element, remove it.

Lastly, the correct closing tag for an `a` element is `</a>`, not `<a/>`.

Once that's been corrected the jQuery to do what you require will simply need to loop over the `.link` elements and append the text from their related `a` element. Try this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $('.link').each((i, el) => {
    $(el).append(` ${$(el).closest('ul').prev('a').text()}`);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navigation">
  <ul id="navigation-item">
    <li class="first">
      <a class="name">Hulk</a>
      <ul>
        <li><p>test 00</p></li>
        <li></li>
        <li><p>test 01</p></li>
        <li><p><a class="link">test 02</a></p></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="second">
      <a class="name">Deadpool</a>
      <ul>
        <li><p>test 00</p></li>
        <li></li>
        <li><p>test 01</p></li>
        <li><p><a class="link">test 02</a></p></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  Array.from($(".link")).forEach(function(elem, index){
    $(elem).append($(".name").eq(index).text());
  })
```

Just replace id with name attribute since W3C recommends creating a single element with an id.